# MySQL multi_query Very Slow, Alternative for Simple Truncate Query?

Tags: php, mysql, json, cron

I have a PHP script set-up that parses over a JSON file that is split up in multiple pages.

This PHP script parses the JSON and inserts it into a MySQL database.

On a single query... (without the `TRUNCATE` statement):

```
if ($count > 0) {

//check toperform operation

foreach ($jsondecode as $entries) {

//getting variables here 

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (title, handle, imagesrc)
VALUES ('".$title."', '".$handle."', '".$imagesrc."')";

if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
 echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error;
}
}
}
```

Results successfully with a  `script execution time: 16.451724052429`

On a multi_query....:

```
if ($count > 0) {
   $sql = "TRUNCATE table;";

foreach ($jsondecode as $entries) {

//getting variables here 

$sql.= "INSERT INTO table (title, handle, imagesrc)
VALUES ('".$title."', '".$handle."', '".$imagesrc."')";

if (!$mysqli->multi_query($sql)) {
echo "Multi query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

do {
if ($res = $mysqli->store_result()) {
    var_dump($res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
    $res->free();
}
} while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());


}
}
```

Results successfully with `script execution time: 278.05182099342`, almost 5 minutes.

All I am trying to do is `TRUNCATE` the table before the `INSERT`.

I am going to be running this on a web server CRON job which is going to execute this script every 12 hours.

There is obviously such a huge execution time difference in the single query vs multi-query... is there anything I can do?

My only thought is to setup another CRON job script that simply does the `TRUNCATE` statement every 12 hours, but 1 minute before this main one runs.  This seems like it should work.. but is of course not ideal as then I'd have to deal with multiple scripts instead of just one.

Comment: Whilst not an answer to your issue, but you can comma separate your insert values too and run it as a single query for multiple items. eg `values (a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i)`

Comment: Execute the `insert` after the query is built, not for every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for such a huge difference the presence of one extra character!

```
$sql.= "INSERT INTO table (title, handle, imagesrc)
VALUES ('".$title."', '".$handle."', '".$imagesrc."')";
```

You keep on adding a new query to the existing query but you continue to execute that ballooning query inside the loop. It may not have been obvious because you have not properly indented your code. So the crucial mistake here is indenting!!

You are truncating the table for each line of input in your JSON, and then inserting the whole thing all over again.

besides, this really isn't a case where you ought to be using multi query. Run the truncate query outside the loop. Then run the insert query inside the loop.

As others have pointed out building a single insert query with multiple VALUES sets might be a bit faster. Alternatively turn transaction auto commit to off and switch back on at the end.

```
if ($count > 0) {
    $connect->query('TRUNCATE `table`');

    //check toperform operation

    foreach ($jsondecode as $entries) {

        //getting variables here 

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (title, handle, imagesrc)
        VALUES ('".$title."', '".$handle."', '".$imagesrc."')";

        if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate? I am trying to wrap my head around this. You say the reason is the presence of one extra character? What character are you talking about...?  Something needs to be indented? Also the TRUNCATE statement is performed outside the loop (after the IF statement and before the FOREACH loop).  I am working on the single insert query but that is taking some time, it should make things faster yes. Thanks for the tips everyone

Comment: Also you are saying this isn't a case where I should be using multi query, but then you say run the TRUNCATE query outside the loop... and then another INSERT query in the loop?  That is two multiple statements.... I was under the impression that to do two statements like this MULTI_QUERY is my only option?

Comment: nopes. These are not multi queries. Just like you can type in different queries into phpmysadmin or mysql console, you can pass queries one by one - exactly as you are doing in your first version.

Comment: Oh wow.  That's easy then. Obviously need to do some more reading on multiqueries but it's working great with the new code.  Thanks so much

Comment: Glad to have been of help